# Access Denied error while connecting to Bitnami Odoo instances in Azure using Node-Odoo

Tags: node.js, odoo

I'm trying to connect the Odoo 12 instances using Node.Js. Using node-odoo to connect the instance. When I connect, I am getting Access denied error, even though I'm able to login to the web portal and Postgre.

The instance is hosted in Azure. the instances are created and hosted using the bitnami service. Odoo is version 12.

```
var Odoo = require('node-odoo');

var odoo = new Odoo({
  host: '<Azure Public IP>',
  port: 80,
  database: 'bitnami_Odoo',
  username: 'postgres',
  password: '<postgres Password>'
});

odoo.connect(function (err) { if (err) { return console.log(err); }
```

return Error Access Denied.

I am able to login to the Odoo web interface with user@example.com ID and its password. Also using Psql I can log into the Postgres using username postgres and the DB password.

But when I connect through Node-Odoo , it gives me an error. I am using Odoo version 12 and Node-Odoo 0.1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Odoo username and password for creating the Odoo object. In your code example it looks like you are using Postgres database username and password.

Comment: Thanks for that. Yes, it solved the issue. was using database username as you mentioned. thanks once again.